# Does Java have something like "shims" in JavaScript, preprocessing in C, or "macros" in general?

Tags: java, macros, compatibility

In the JavaScript world it often happens that a user's browser does not implement a feature but it can be supported by adding some additional code as a work-around. This is often called a "shim" (or "shiv"). In C I have done something similar at compile-time using preprocessing like `#define ENABLE_XYZ_SUPPORT 1` and then `#if ENABLE_XYZ_SUPPORT 1`.

**Is there something like this in Java?** Namely, I would like to be able to compile some source code designed for Java 1.7 with Java 1.6. Perhaps there is a library for this if there is no built-in language construct?

**Background:** I am somewhat new to Java and am developing my first significantly large project (basically a servlet that conditionally assembles data from various sources). Since this is a brand new project it seemed reasonable to take advantage of some of the new features of Java 1.7 such as implementing the `AutoCloseable` interface for objects rather than just `Closeable` so that they could be used with `try-with-resources`. However, it would be nice if this application could be built to run on Java 1.6 as well in case it needed to. If I could add a parameter or something to enable defining my own `AutoCloseable` interface then this could compile since I am not actually using `try-with-resources` -- just trying to use the most appropriate interfaces.

I realize that I could do something like have maven run an external tool to replace AutoCloseable with Closeable if it were building for 1.6. However, that's not really what I'm looking for (not general enough).

***Update:*** To clarify, I'm wondering if I can do something conditionally at compile-time like this:

```
#if java version < 1.7

    public interface AutoCloseable {
        void close() throws Exception;
    }

#endif
```

BTW, I am using maven with this project, so if it has a feature that would help here that might be worth considering.

Comment: There are [others that asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526007/how-to-make-a-library-which-uses-autocloseable-and-also-support-java-6), too. What you want is a back port. I suggest you assume [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and just write your application and get it running.

Comment: Sorry for not seeing that other question. The search queries I tried did not turn it up ("java shim", "java preprocessing", etc.). Which part am I never going to need: 1.6 support or AutoCloseable interface?  I will keep developing the app for 1.7 and deal with making a 1.6 backport/version if and when the time comes.

Comment: Are you sure supporting Java 6 is worthwhile? After all, it's been [end-of-life for 4 months now](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) ...

Comment: Why do you think you'll need to support Java 6? You don't manage the server? If you have concerns, write it for Java 6 (1.6), there aren't too many changes and you'll prevent headaches.

Comment: @meriton, thanks for pointing that out. I did not know it was EOL, just that my company is still using it. This helps steer my decision; I'll probably just try to be firm about only supporting 1.7+

Comment: @IgorRodriguez, exactly: I will not have the final say about the server's environment. It just feels wrong to make something that is "old" from its very beginning.

Comment: @iX3 That's exactly what I meant, deal with it when you really need it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run java code that makes uses of the new construct of java 7 (such as `try-with-resources`) on java 6 JVMs, so there's no compiler or code trick that will help you on that, unfortunately. You should have two codebases if you want to support and old version.

Comment: I understand that, but I am not actually using the try-with-resources construct (see question background) or any other language construct specific to 1.7. I just wanted to know about conditionally loading a "shim" class/interface that would define things like AutoCloseable when they weren't natively available.

Comment: Ok, but then we are curious to know how you intend to use `AutoCloseable` if not using `try-with-resources`. Serious question! I would see a real need only with that statement.

Comment: The resource class that would be implementing AutoCloseable is public and may be used in other projects that do not need to support 1.6.

Comment: Sorry, I think that it's not gonna work. It would be nice though :) The thing is that, you can have a library that supports both versions (compiled `-target 1.6`) but that will not use `AutoCloseable` and so even java 7 JVMs won't be able to use the object with `try-with-resources`, or use `AutoCloseable` that will break java 6 compatibility. What you are looking for are Macros (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)), that are not part of the Java world, yet :)

Comment: OK, yeah I was proposing that for Java 1.6 we import our own AutoCloseable interface (identical to the one in Java 1.7) so it knows what it is (though it won't work with try-with-resources) and when compiling for 1.7 this definition would just not be included. Thanks for the note about the term macro -- I had almost forgotten that term, and you're right in that it's basically what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

> Since this is a brand new project it seemed reasonable to take advantage of some of the new features of Java 1.7 such as implementing the AutoCloseable interface for objects rather than just Closeable so that they could be used with try-with-resources. However, it would be nice if this application could be built to run on Java 1.6 as well in case it needed to.

This is a no go with Java - it's backwards compatible, but not forwards compatible. If you try and hack your way around getting various Java 7 language features in Java 6 (of which `AutoCloseable` is one) you'll end up with a horrific mess of a project that would cause many more problems than it solved.

Java 7 support is relatively widespread now - it wasn't for a while but that situation has now changed, so I don't think it's unreasonable to require anyone building or running the application to have Java 7 installed. If this is something you have to have, then I'm afraid the only sensible option is to forfeit the Java 7 language features and target 1.6 directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're close methods only throw IOExceptions, you can implement Closeable.  This interface was introduced in Java 1.5.  In Java 7, it was modified to extend AutoCloseable.  Your library should then support try with resources for clients that are using Java 7, but still be compatible with Java 6.

I've not tried this, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. It makes sense for addressing the specific "AutoCloseable" part, but the goal of the question was really to find something more general (e.g. including some classes during compilation when using one version but not in another, etc.).